# Travel to Jordan, cross Israeli border and fly back from Tel Aviv

Tags: visas, borders, israel, jordan

A friend (Swiss citizen) and I (French citizen) plan on going hiking in Jordan and Israel in February and March.

What we plan to do:

- We will arrive by the same flight (but separately) in Queen Alia International Airport (Jordan). We get our Jordan visas there.
- We hike for a few weeks on the Jordan Trail, finishing in Aqaba (Red Sea).
- We cross the Israeli border at Wadi Araba Crossing / Yitzhak Rabin Crossing
  (getting Israeli visas there) and start hiking on the Israel National Trail.
- We join Tel-Aviv from our stop point (we don't know yet where we will stop hiking, as it will depend on our walking pace) and fly back home from David-Ben-Gurion airport.

Are there any caveats to this plan?

Comment: Note that the exit stamp from Jordan will imply that you are going to Israel, even if Israel doesn't stamp your passport. This has implications for future travel plans in several Muslim countries.

Comment: Can we ask to get stamped on a piece of paper? (I actually plan on going in Iran someday)

Comment: The Internet says Jordan [will stamp](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293985-i2131-k8471463-Can_I_request_no_entry_stamp_for_Jordan-Jordan.html) your passport, period. It doesn't matter if Israel does, because Jordanian exit through the Aqaba land border is a tell-tale sign you went to Israel, regardless of stamps. There's disagreement on this site whether Iran views a visit to Israel as a complete automatic visa disqualifier. Some other countries (e.g., Saudia) appear to retain this policy, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you walk from Amman to Aqaba you'll stay quite a long time in Jordan.

I guess you'll see Wadi mujib, Petra, maybe even Wadi rum ... It could worth to buy a Jordan pass.

I don't see any problem to join Israel in your itinerary although you should check the border status few days before you arrive.

Answer (score 6):

From a visa point of view, **your plan sounds fine**.  Be sure to arrive early at Ben Gurion, because you may get selected for extra questioning.  Enjoy your trip!